# Is a sitara ARM powerful enough to decode and play mpeg4

Tags: linux, arm, mpeg

I have the question: "Is a sitara ARM running embedded linux is powerful enough to decode and play mpeg4 format files (using vlc or other software)?"

posed to me by the boss... but I am not really sure how to answer it! Anyone have any ideas how I cam go about answering that?

I was thinking to get an embedded linux with vlc in the distribution and then trying to play the mpeg 4, but that will take a considerable effort on my part, so before I start I am researching.

(edited this as sitara is not arm9, its arm cortex a8, sorry)

Comment: I really don't know much about these hardware, but if you put some of the ARM chip spec side by side (and I'm assuming you know more about ARM cpu than me) can you determine if one is more powerful than the other? If you can, one comparison would be the ARM11 CPU used by Raspberry Pi. It is capable of decoding and play full 1080p video files (tested using RaspBMC). If you can find out if the arm CPU used by Raspberry pi is better / worst off, then it may be a good comparison for your decision.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not find ARM11 on the TI website :( But it's useful to know the rasberry pi can do HDMI. I will try to find the ARM spec from the rasberry pi website, thanks.